# Limiting number of connections in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I recently learned node.js, and I'm having fun rewriting perl scripts into non-blocking scripts. I am currently writing a script to go out and connect to some hosts and pull some data.  I'm pulling the connection data from a database, and would like to limit it to x connections (probably 50) at a time, with new connections starting up when one is complete.

Here's the code I'm playing with:

```
var net = require('net');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var mysql_conn = mysql.createConnection({
    //connection info...
});

var connect_hash ={};


function make_connection (id, ip, port, username, password, cb) {
        var conn = net.createConnection(port, ip);
        var completeData = '';
        connect_hash[id] = {};
        connect_hash.id.ip = ip;

    // stuff happens here..
}


mysql_conn.query("select id, IP, Port, Username, Password from Hosts",
  function (err, ne_records, fields){
        if (err) throw err;

        ne_records.forEach(function(host){
                make_connection(host.id, host.IP, host.Port, host.Username, host.Password, function(attempt) {
                        delete connection_hash[id];
                        db_save (attempt);
                });
        });
});
```

As written right now, it'll just open connections to every host in the table and do stuff on them.  I'd really like it to open a specified number at a time, and only start new connections when the old ones are done and deleted out of connection_hash.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: In pseudo-babble: create an object which holds a queue, push to queue, on add event to queue check current connections, if below limit, run connection instantly & remove, if above, keep in queue, and on finished events of connection pop data from the queue if not empty & start that connection?

Comment: I also just noticed [node-mysql's 'streaming query rows'](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#streaming-query-rows).  I could probably use that.

Comment: @coding_hero: Streaming query rows probably won't do too much for you since you'll get results from the MySQL server *much* faster than you can do your network requests.  In other words, the SQL results will all arrive within a second, and you're right back to where you started: making tons of connections at the same time (±1s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple – keep a queue of hosts to be connected to, and only open *n* connections at a time.  When a connection completes (or fails), start the next one in the queue.

You might want to take a look at how the [HTTP `Agent` class](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.10.18/lib/http.js#L1213-1340) is implemented.  It does what you're trying to accomplish for HTTP requests.

Comment: Oh, duh.  Sometimes I get confused because node is non-blocking, and I forget that all my old programming knowledge still works.